# Are Intents queued after being sent?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

Consider the following scenario:

One `Service`has registered a `BroadcastReceiver`whose `IntentFilter` has several actions. If one of such actions were to be received while another one is being processed, will it be queued or will it be aborted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Intent` will be queued until it can be delivered. If your receiver takes too long, Android may decide to kill its process (but if this happens, the logcat output will be clear on the reason).